# Which is the most appropriate place to store or keep the Qur'an?

Tags: quran

I have heard people say to keep it at a height and not at a very low place.
See the diagram below.
[image]

3, 4, 5 would obviously be permissible (provided my hands reach 5) but can I keep at 1 & 2? Won't that be low?

Comment: Nice diagram. ;) Consider the risk of dropping it accidentally if you place it in 4 or 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to place Qur'an in a place higher than ground. However, there is no harm in placing it in a ritually pure ground as well if it is **out of necessity** and **not out of contempt**.

> “A group of Jews came and called the Messenger of Allah to Quff. So he
>   visited them in their school. They said, ‘O Abul Qasim, one of our men
>   has committed fornication with a woman, so pass judgment concerning
>   them. They placed a cushion for the Messenger of Allaah, and he sat on
>   it. Then he said, ‘Bring the Torah.’ It was brought, and he took the
>   cushion from beneath him and placed the Torah on it and said: ‘I
>   believe in you and in Him Who revealed you.’...”

Saheeh Sunan Abee Dawud (no. 4439). This hadeeth was declared hasan (sound) by Shaykh Albaani.

If that is what Prophet salallahu alayhi wassalam did for Torah because it has Allah's words, then think about Qur'an which is superior to Torah.

To sum up, the Mus-haf should and is worthier to be put on an elevated place. However, it is not disliked or prohibited to keep it in a ritually pure ground.

Comment: I found a link for http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/40/99, but it's referenced as #4449 instead. Not sure if this is the exact same one that was declared *hasan* so I'm not editing it into your answer myself.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly this is a Mustahab (recommend) and please do not make religion much complicated because others may fear entering Islam.
And it is only a means to respect the Quran because it is not a creature and or creator but Quran is word of Allah (کلام الله). Only respect it.
Also it is recommended to do not put Quran in the room you sleep or it is said do not put other book on Quran.
 It is said by some scholars do not read Quran while sleeping. but none of them are Wajib (Obligatory) and are for Muslim's want to reach higher spiritual rank and become a close friend of God and meet God and even died before death (optional death).

Muslim can understand how to respect Quran on their own.

Let me say the memory of one scholar:

> He said one day I went to a Great Scholar (Ayatollah Ghazi) and asked
>   him: I have heard some people when read Quran they can see the
>   paradise. why I can not? he replied: they do not read Quran while
>   sleeping. I wondered how he knew I read Quran while sleeping and only
>   myself was aware of it.